# Plotly graph title and labels are off white color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, cufflinks

I have generated the below plotly graph using the code as below :

```
x=['a','b','c','d']

y=['1','2','3','4']

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

fig=df.iplot(kind= 'scatter', size =9,mode='markers+text',opacity=0.8, colors=['blue'], yTitle= 'Count',xTitle = 'x', asFigure=True)

fig.update_layout(height=300, width=500, title_text="Plot X on Y",barmode='stack',template='plotly_dark',  plot_bgcolor='rgb(17,17,17)',
    legend = dict(bgcolor = 'rgb(17,17,17)', orientation="h",yanchor="bottom", x=1,y=1.02, xanchor='right'), paper_bgcolor ='rgb(12,12,12)', xaxis = {'showgrid': False, 'zeroline':True}, yaxis = {'showgrid': False})
```

The graph is coming as below with the title, xaxis, yaxis label titles are all appearing in suppressed color. I want them to be in a sharp white color.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several themes you can try out. If you use 'solar', you will get the color you want. The source of the theme can be found [here](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/blob/master/cufflinks/themes.py) for your reference.

```
fig=df.iplot(kind= 'scatter', size =9,
             mode='markers+text',
             opacity=0.8,
             colors=['blue'],
             yTitle= 'Count',
             xTitle = 'x',
             asFigure=True,
             theme='solar')
```

[image]